# Filtering Korean words/characters?

Tags: ios, xcode, filter, localization

I'm a beginner and learning through doing. I made a list of universities on a tableview and I had a searchbar to filter the list. It is still working perfectly with English letters, but not for the Korean letters.

```
    var filteredUniversities = University.generateUniversities()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchBarSetup()
}

func searchBarSetup() {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width), height: 70))
    searchBar.delegate = self

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
}

//MARK: Search Bar Delegate

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    //called when text changes (or clears)

    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredUniversities = University.generateUniversities()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }else {
        filterTableView(text: searchText)
    }
}

func filterTableView(text:String) {
    filteredUniversities = filteredUniversities.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
        return (mod.name.contains(text))
    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Does anyone know how to make the .filter recognize Korean letters? My universities are listed as follows. (there are many more, but they all follow the same format)

```
class func generateUniversities() -> [University]{
    var universities: [University] = []

    universities.append(University(name: "파고다 어학원", location: "부산", photo: UniversityPhotoDictionary["PAG"]!))
    universities.append(University(name: "부산대학교", location: "부산", photo: UniversityPhotoDictionary["PNU"]!))
    universities.append(University(name: "동아대학교", location: "부산", photo: UniversityPhotoDictionary["DAU"]!))
```

return universities.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name} )
    }

Strangely, the sorted() method can handle the Korean characters, but it seems like the filter method is breaking down. (only for Korean characters, the English ones are fine)

So if I type in 파고다, it filters everything out and there are no universities to choose from.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to convert both the text and the university's name to lowercase and compare them that way: `mod.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())`

Comment: I had the lowercased() initially, but then removed it. I thought it might be the reason the Korean wasn't filtering, since Korean has no upper or lower casing. I'll add it back, but that's not the problem. Thanks for responding though!

Comment: Please add the name of the universities and your search text you are trying to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're working on a Korean keyboard, and when you type 파, I assume you first press ㅍ and then press ㅏ. (Forgive me if I'm wrong about the specifics of how you're typing here; my Korean is horrible, but I suspect you're doing something similar to this.)

Pressing ㅍ calls your filter routine (since it changes the text field). None of the strings contain ㅍ, so it removes everything. You then press ㅏ and it composes the character 파 and filters again, but everything's already gone.

You don't want to keep reassigning `filteredUniversities`. You want to filter every time on the full list. That way, even though you get nothing for ㅍ, you'll get a list for 파.

If you copy 파고다 and then paste it into this field (rather than typing it), I bet it works, since the filtering routine will only be called once.

Comment: You're a genius. I copy/pasted it and you are correct. I don't quite understand how to fix the problem yet. But I'm very happy to know what the problem is.